# unbind event handlers while ajax in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field with keypress event handler [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w98AS/3/). And when I type something in this field and press "Enter" 2 times, 2 requests will be send. I want to turn off all events, while ajax request in progress. One option is to call `.off()` function before ajax call, and then bind event handler again. Any other options?

Comment: I suppose you could set `async: false`

Comment: Use a flag (a variable or data attribute), but why not off() that's what it's there for.

Comment: `async: false` is a TERRIBLE idea. It completely locks up the JavaScript event loop. If your user does other things in the mean time, the JavaScript attached to that will also be unresponsive. And I think you will actually get requests for each keydown, they're just serialized (delayed).

Comment: You could `disable` the textbox before the Ajax request is started and then once it is complete re-enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use 2 boolean flags, like:

```
var is_requesting = false, should_request = false;
function onkeydown() {
    if (is_requesting) {
        should_request = true;
        return;
    }
    is_requesting = true;
    $.ajax({}, function () {
        is_requesting = false;
        if (should_request) {
            onkeydown();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the need for the `should_request` boolean, could you explain it?

Comment: It's means to buffer requests. If you call the function five times it will call the ajax twice. This approach is useful for things like autocomplete. You'll never get competing requests and you will always get the last event. You can leave it off if you think you wont need it.

Answer (score 2):

use the callback handlers from your ajax call and a boolean used as flag. By setting the ajaxLoading boolean to false in the "always" callback, you can be sure that other, future requests can be made independent from whether the current ajax call throws an error or not.

```
var ajaxLoading = false;

if(!ajaxloading){
   ajaxloading=true;
   $.ajax({
    url: 'your url',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON'

   })
   .done(function(data) {
    console.log("success");

   })
   .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
   })
   .always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
        ajaxloading=false;
   });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a good reason for you not to use the jQuery [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function?

If so then you could simply disable the control prior to making the ajax request and re-enable it once the request is complete. This would also stop the user from thinking he/she could change the result by changing the text value during the request.

```
        //Disable the input        
        $('#myresult').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#myresult').append('<br>'+$(this).val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function() {},
            complete: function() {
                //Re-Enable the input
                $('#myresult').prop('disabled', false);
            },
            url: "/echo/json/",
            data: { delay : 3 },
            success: function(){},
            error: function() {},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

Comment: don't like to bind/unbind often. it's annoying me. Disabling input field is good idea, thank you. I will combine it with boolean flag